# If else com funções

Tags: javascript, if, else, funções

Há possibilidade de utilizar um `if-else` com funções "function();"
exemplo:

```
if (a > 1){function Save();}
 else {function NoSave();}
```

Só preciso saber se funções carregadas no `head` funcionam dentro de `if-else` em *scripts* dentro do `body`, se sim como.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se você quer chamar a função, claro funciona, mas a sintaxe não seria esta, seria assim:

```
if (a > 1) {
    Save();
} else {
    NoSave();
}
```

Mas se você quer definir funções condicionalmente, aí não é possível, pelo menos não desta forma. Você até poderia definir duas funções anônimas, assim:

```
var salvar;
if (a > 1) {
    salvar = function() { /*faz alguma coisa que seria o você quer no Save() */ };
} else {
    salvar = function() { /*faz outra coisa ou eventualmente não faz nada, seria o NoSave() */ };
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/DefineConditionally.js).

Aí em algum lugar você chamaria `salvar()`.

E poderia fazer algo assim também:

```
let salvar;
salvar = a > 1 ? function() { /*faz alguma coisa que seria o você quer no Save() */ } :
    function() { /*faz outra coisa ou eventualmente não faz nada, seria o NoSave() */ };
```

Provavelmente tem um jeito melhor de fazer o que você precisa mas sem detalhes só poderia sugerir isto.

Comment: Deu certo :) . Eu sou Bur.. mesmo.
Muito Obrigado.
Utilizarei em um if com confirmação de existência de um determinado arquivo, se arquivo existir solicitará confirmação se confirmado roda o Save(); se não confirmada retorna false, se o documento não existe roda o Save(); também desta forma está perfeitamente funcionando.

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade é melhor vc criar as funções antes e quando precisar chamá-las, usar o if. Por exemplo:

```
function Save(){
    ...
}

function NoSave(){
    ...
}

if(a > 1){
    Save();
}else{
    NoSave();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue deixar seu código menor também usando ternários:

```
(a > 1) ? save() : noSave()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você poder utilizar, mas você deve declará-las antes e usar da seguinte forma dentro do if:

```
function T()
{
    if (a > 1)
    {
        Save();
    }else {
        NoSave();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resposta curta:** Sim é possível usar, e existem varias formas, sendo uma delas:

```
if (day == 1){
  (function(){
    alert()
  })()
}
```

**Resposta longa:**

Isso que você esta querendo se chama função anonima, que é nada mais que uma função sem nome e que não é acessível depois.

Algo que você pode fazer para não perder essa "função sem nome" é salvar ela dentro de uma variavel,

```
let awesomeFunc = ()=>{ alert("Olá mundo!") }
```

e depois só chamando ela

```
awesomeFunc()
```

è possível usar parametros como qualquer outra função

```
   let awesomeFunc = (mensagem)=>{ alert(mensagem) }

    awesomeFunc("Olá mundo lindo")
```

**Recomendo ler os links a baixo:**

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-anonymous-functions/
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp